# Formsets validate_min is not working properlly

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I have a formset with multiple forms:

```
PodFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(parent_model=PodP, model=Prod, form=PofModelForm, min_num=1, max_num=4,validate_min=True, extra=3)
```

The issues is that validate_min is not working properly:

If the user complete another form than the first one, validate_min doesn't work, say is invalid, which is not, because at least a form is completed but not the first one.

How can I override/fix this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember (please correct me if I'm wrong) formsets in Django are not clever enough to validate against out-of-order forms. It means that 
validation expects form with index (*id*) 0 to be present if `min_num > 0`  and you will have to re-format forms' indices. This is usually done on the front-end.

Comment: I don't know what form the user will use, the user can jump between forms; ordering on front-end doesn't solve the jump;  So how can I do my own validation then ?